# Trying to get a app that has a registration error

Tags: macos, cache, plist

I have a app called codekit I installed but it gives me a registration error and just quits the app. I emailed the creator and he told me to do this

Delete everything. The app, the plist, the folder `~/Library/CodeKit`, any caches in your /var or /usr folders --- all of it has to be cleared out

I don't see a plist file in the library and how do I clear caches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting these files first:

- `~/Library/Preferences/com.incident57.CodeKit.plist`
- `~/Library/Caches/com.incident57.CodeKit/`

There might not even be any files in `/var/` or `/usr/`, but you can try searching for other support files with `mdfind codekit` or `sudo find /var/ -iname '*codekit*'`.